# Angular Directives does not working when i called datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datetimepicker

Here, i have called my angular js directives when i click my data time field but it does not called directives.

```
<input datetimepicker1 ng-model="TaskModel.received_date" style="width: 260px;" type="text" name="received_date" class="form-control selva"  required="" id="from_date"/>
```

This is my html code.

```
timeTracker.directive('datetimepicker1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datetimepicker({
                format: "DD-MM-YYYY",
                 minDate:yesterday,
            }).on('dp.change', function(e) {

                scope.TaskModel.received_date = e.target.value;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And this my Angular JS calling Directives

Answer (score 0):

There could be one of several things here:

1. You are not adding the directive to your angular module. Make sure that your link function is being called and that you are registering the directive properly.
2. THe `dp.change`, event is not being raised. Make sure you are properly raising this event when you expect it to.
3. You have no dateTimePicker directive associated with this html element. I see your custom directive but no date time picker. Make sure it is applied to this element as well.

Upon thinking deeper, I think the problem you are having is #3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to handle a click function on your directive you must do as follows:

```
timeTracker.directive('datetimepicker1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                //run after click on the field
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The datetimepicker1 doesn't exist in the element.